# Mapping Json to POJO

Tags: java, android, gson

```
{
    "Filters": [{
        "Decription": "Default",
        "FieldSelected": {
            "AppointmentDate": true,
            "AppointmentDateOrder": 1            
            "ptStatusOrder": 3
        },
        "FilterID": 1
    }, {
        "Decription": "chart",
        "FieldSelected": {
            "AppointmentDate": true,
            "AppointmentDateOrder": 1,           
            "ptStatusOrder": 0
        },
        "FilterID": 2
    }]
}
```

I am getting a response of this structure, how do i map it to my POJO class. Can anyone give a sample `POJO` class for this `json` structure. I am using `Gson` for Request and Response.

Comment: Hint: It's an object that has `List` of `Filter`. `Filter` in an object that has three attributes `Description`, `FilterId`, and another object called `FieldSelected`. Field selected can be treated as a `Map`. You may write a POJO for `FieldSelect` if wanted. `FieldSelect` has three attrs `AppointmentDate`, `AppointmentDateOrder` and `ptStatusOrder`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just map one Json Object as a Java Class. And make an Array of Object as a List..

Like, (pseudo code only)

You are using **GSON** library so import `SerializedName` in your pojo classes.

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;
```

Pojo Class looks like,

```
public class Filter {

    @SerializedName("Decription") // This requires same as your Json key 
    public String description;
    @SerializedName("FieldSelected") // The Json Object of FieldSelected
    public Field listDetails;

}

public class Field {
    @SerializedName("ptStatusOrder")
    public int status;
    @SerializedName("AppointmentDateOrder")
    public int dateOrder;
    @SerializedName("AppointmentDate")
    public boolean appDate;
}
```

And main **ListFileter** class,

```
public class ListFilter {

        @SerializedName("Filters") 
        public List<Filter> listFilter;

    }
```

And in Android code,

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
ListFilter listFilter = gson.fromJson(jsonResponse, ListFilter.class);
```